# Добавление иконки к JButton

Tags: java, swing

Есть класс

```
public class AddOpenButtons extends JButton {
public AddOpenButtons() {
    JButton buttonAdd = new JButton("New Button");
    ImageIcon icon1 = createIcon("images/edit-add.png");
    buttonAdd.setIcon(icon1);
    buttonAdd.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    buttonAdd.setSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
}
protected ImageIcon createIcon(String path) {
    URL imgURL = AddOpenButtons.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("File not found " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Потом в классе фрейма создаю новую кнопку

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    private AddOpenButtons button1;
    public final int width = 400;
    public final int height = 400;

    //Конструктор
    public MainFrame(){
             setSize(width, height);

           //Создаём панель для отображения кнопок
             panel = new JPanel();
           // Добавляем button к панели
             button1 = new AddOpenButtons();
             panel.add(button1);
           // Добавляем панель к фрейму
             add(panel);
             setVisible(true);
             setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Кнопка отображается без названия и картинки + пишет, что картинка не найдена, картинка лежит в подпаке класса images. Создаю всё в eclipse...
Что-то туплю немного, подскажите, что не так делаю??

Comment: ImageIcon icon1 = createIcon("images/edit-add.png"); 

а если задать абсолютный путь к картинке, тоже не работает?

Comment: нет...

Comment: А может быть такое, что при создании кнопки во фрейме, определяется конструктор JButton по умолчанию в место моего и поэтому создается пустая кнопка??
(45 минут назад)AleXpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Папка images должна лежать в той же папке, что и папка src.
**UPD**: чем плох вариант `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/middle.gif")`?

Comment: А может быть такое, что при создании кнопки во фрейме, определяется конструктор JButton по умолчанию и поэтому создается пустая кнопка??